# Remove Ampersand from an input xml during xslt transformation

Tags: xslt, escaping, ampersand

I am new to xslt. I have an input xml and that has to be sorted. To get the sorted output xml, a xslt has been built and sorting is working fine. But if the one of the tags (sorting is not based on this tag) in the input xml contains '&', the xslt transformation fails while parsing the input xml.
how to escape the '&' in the input xml from compilation.

Comment: Pleas share your xml and xslt. Both can be as little as possible but gives an better understanding of what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just posted the fix we did to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "the input XML contains '&'", that's technically incorrect: if it contains an unescaped '&' then it's not XML.

If you're asking how to escape the ampersand correctly while generating the XML, then that depends on the tools you are using to generate the XML.

If you're asking how to fix broken XML containing unescaped ampersands, then the answer in the general case is that you can't (there's a reason they have to be escaped, after all). But a search for XML and ampersand will find plenty of suggestions for partial solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your response. As you told, the xml was having unescaped '&'. Example:  Test A & B .. So during the xslt transformation, it was failing while parsing the xml. After making the change in the source system as

the parsing is working fine.